# Is is correct to say ~亡くなりなりました?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

Did I hear it wrong? And should it be 彼女は亡くなり **に** なりました?

I am watching Japanese movies to improve my listening. In a movie a character said:

> 彼女は亡くなりなりました

Mentioned that I know the rule:

> Na-adjective/noun: **~ に なります**
>   I-adjective/nai: **~く なります**

My listening is not good yet.

Comment: Maybe it was お亡くなりになりました?

Comment: It was about a girl, so 彼女は~

Comment: For the usage/meaning of the honorific 「お + verb stem + になります」 form: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14270/9831 ・  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2590/9831

Comment: I am aware of honorific `お`. But the conversation was between 2 friends. I guess Japanese people don't use honorific `お` while talking with friends.

Comment: 亡くなりになりました and 亡くなりなりました are both incorrect. It should be either 亡くなりました or honorific お亡くなりになりました.

Comment: Look, you use 尊敬語 (honorific/respectful language) to show respect to the **agent/subject of the verb** . Here, the subject of the verb 亡くなる is not the friend the speaker is speaking to, is it? The honorific お～～になる is used to show respect to 彼女.

Comment: The dead person is a girl who is the close friend of both speaker and listener (did you watch the movie "Gomen Nasai" ? >> a girl writes shousetsu and whoever reads her shousetsu dies). Maybe you are right, but not sure this is correct or not in my specified context.

Comment: @Hassan Makarov It is not true that honorific お is totally dropped with friends. (For what it's worth, お + masu-form + になる is a separate structure, different from simply adding お to things like すし or 金.) However, given the context, なくなります is most likely.

Comment: The expression '彼女は亡くなりなりました。' sounds odd to me as a native Japanese speaker. So is '彼女は亡くなりになりました。'.  These expressions are so odd that if a spy smuggled into Japan uses such an expression, he/she will be spotted immediately (cf.  the bar scene in the movie 'Inglourious Basterds')  :-) As Shoko wrote, '彼女は亡くなりました。' and '彼女はお亡くなりになりました。' sound natural. I guess either of these expressions was spoken very fast or in a small voice, and that you heard as you wrote.

Comment: This might be a long-shot, but are you sure it wasn't **亡くなられました**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a mishearing and is unable to be answered as is.

Answer (score 0):

The rules you mention apply to adjectives. 亡くなる is a verb and 亡くなり~ is its ~ます stem.